# i feel confused with jquery's load

Tags: jquery, dom, load, this, ready

with jquery,how can i do something just after the dom loaded,i write like this:

```
<script>
$("#google").load(function() {
  alert('ok');
});
</script>
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" id="google" />
```

but nothing happen~ 
if i use ready() instead of load like this:

```
 <script>
    $("#google").ready(function() {
      alert(this);
      alert('ok');
    });
    </script>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" id="google" />
```

,it will work ,but the pointer "this" will not be $("#google"),and it seems to be "window" or other things,i feel confused~

Comment: Could you tell us whether that image is dynamically generated or hard-coded in your html ?

Comment: it's hard-coded and what i want is that the function work after the dom loaded~ not all the document dom tree loaded ,as sometimes the dom tree is too big~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first bind the event handler to the load event, then set the image's src to actually start the load.

```
$('#google').bind("load", function() {
    alert('ok');
});
$("#google").attr("src", "http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png");
```

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/VaLhf/

Comment: If you're going with this approach, a safe practice is to let the image initially point to a transparent pixel or something like that, because some browsers will interpret an omitted `src` just like they interpret a `form` without an `action`, i.e. as a reference back to itself, and cause a second request to the page the image resides on. That can cause some oddities if you're executing serverside script on that page. And if you are referencing a transparent pixel from the beginning, you better check sure your `load` listener to verify that it's not *that* image that is being fired.

Comment: i seems that it works after $(window).loaded like this:
 $(window).load(function(){
    $('#google').bind("load", function() {       
      alert('ok');});$("#google").attr("src", "http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"); 


 });  

i think it will be a good method to solve the load problem,through dynamic add attribute ~TX

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly you want to manipulate `#google` **after** the DOM is fully loaded. Then what you want to use is actually `$(document).ready(function() {//do stuff with #google});`

`.load()` is used to make ajax requests. You should read up on it [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

It would also be interesting to know whether #google is dynamically generated or not.

Oh and in your second example, you can't do `alert(this)`. `alert()` just takes a string as a parameter.

Comment: @wong2 Thing is he doesn't describe exactly how the image comes into all this... Edit: I've just asked him.

Comment: @David : The reason I asked is in case he took the code from Firebug or Web Inspector ;) But yeah it stands to reason that the image is already there in the code.

Comment: i learn the load event from jquery's website:http://api.jquery.com/load-event/
and it can be use in many doms “This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.” what i want is the function work just after the dom loaded

Comment: @Dafims, and you're not inherently using it wrong, it's just that in your particular scenario, you don't seem to need it.

Comment: @ Guy Fawkes ,TX i used $(document).ready to solve the problem that all doms loaded, so i want to know if some methods will work after some special dom loaded~

Answer (score 1):

In your first code, you're looking a `#google` element and tells it to notify you when its image is loaded. However, at the time where the javascript is executed (*above* the element, in the code), there *exists* no `#google` element, and so the event listener is not assigned to anything.

Sadly, adding the event listener inside a `DOMReady` listener won't always solve the problem either. If, for instance, the image is already in browser cache, the `#google` load event may occur *before* `DOMReady`. The safest approach seems to be to attach the listener immediately *after* the image is created.

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" id="google" />
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#google').load(function() {
   alert('ok');
});

</script>
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/akura4/edit)

If you're not happy with injecting a script block in the middle of your code like that, but want to defer your script to someplace later, you can always listen to `$(window).load()` instead of `$('#google').load()`. This is equivalent to `<body onload="">`, i.e. it will run when *all* external content has been loaded. So when `$(window).load()` occurs, you know that your `#google` image has loaded, but it's not guaranteed to be *immediately* after it's loaded.

Comment: works in jsbin, but not in jsfiddle, that's because you have to add the <script></script> immediately after the <img />. I think it's not nice..

Comment: TX~ i works~
follow your mind,i want to know if jquery's live event will work as its Description: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
but it seems that

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
    var that = $("#google");
    alert(that);
});
```

This code will run when the DOM is fully loaded, as triggered by the `$(document)` [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("The DOM has loaded");
});
```

The .load function is used to trigger an ajax call and place the response in the div specified.

Comment: as i know "$(document).ready" will work after all dom loaded, what i want is after the "#google" dom loaded,sometimes we got a large html file and we want the script works after some dom loaded~